# field slideshow module and image field caption

Tags: nodes, media, entities

I want to use image field caption and  [field slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_slideshow).

How can I set the caption field as caption for my slideshow?

I tried to apply the [update](https://www.drupal.org/node/1366226) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1366226#comment-8420833) particular patch? Do you use 'Long text' field? I think that this patch doesn't work with standard 'Text' field.